# Unable to design an Azure Logic App from VS 2015

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am currently developing an Azure Logic App. This is very straight-forward from portal, but I need to use Visual Studio as an IDE for this. I have followed all the steps mentioned in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-deploy-from-vs/ article, but when I try to do right-click "<>.json" and say "Open in Logic App Designer", the Visual Studio crashes everytime.

Could anyone please assist on the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you currently signed into Visual Studio with an account containing valid Azure subscriptions/currently has strong internet connectivity? That is known to cause editing issues before.

If that does not solve your problem, we have enabled logging feature in our most recent update (ver 1.0.0):
a.       Open developer command prompt for VS2015

b.      Run following  command to start VS with activity logging enabled.
devenv.exe /log
c.       Repro the issue in this instance and close it.
d.      You can find the activity log at location :
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml
e.      Please send us this file to us.

If you can share the logs with logicappsbug@microsoft.com, we can further assist you on this specific problem.
Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 1):

I has a similar issue, I found I had to install the Azure Logic Apps Tools (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VinaySinghMSFT.AzureLogicAppsToolsforVisualStudio), restart Visual Studio and then create the Azure Resource Group project for it to work.

The project that I had generated without the tool installed did not work (ever).

I'm using the Azure SDK 2.9.6, Visual Studio 2015 update 3